# Show the singular support of $\delta(p(x))$ agree with it's support

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n| p(x)=0, \nabla p(x)\not= 0, p(x)\in C^{\infty}\}$. We defined the distribution $\delta(p(x))\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ on $S$ as follows: for all $\varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ 
$$ \langle \delta(p(x)),\varphi\rangle:=\int_{p(x)=0}\varphi(x) dS_{x}.$$
Show that 
$$ \text{sing}~\text{supp}~\delta(p(x))=\text{supp}~\delta(p(x))=\{x|p(x)=0\}.$$
Here $\text{sing}~\text{supp}~u$ is the singular support of a distribution $u$.

I only know that $ \text{supp}~\delta(p(x))=\{x|p(x)=0\}$ and $\text{sing}~\text{supp}~\delta(p(x))\subset\text{supp}~\delta(p(x))$, but I don't know how to prove that
$\text{supp}~\delta(p(x))\subset \text{sing}~\text{supp}~\delta(p(x))$. Can someone help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is the meaining of $p(x)\in C^\infty$ in the definition of $S$? You mean that $p$ is smooth at $x$?

Comment: The way you phrase the definition of $S, p$ is a dummy variable whose value ranges over smooth functions (and FYI: $S = \Bbb R^n$). As a dummy variable, $p$ is undefined outside that one expression defining $S$. Yet you reference it outside. Do you perhaps actually mean: "Let $p \in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ and define $S = \{x\in \Bbb R^n \mid p(x) = 0, \nabla p(x) \ne 0\}$" ?